# How to obtain squares in squares with CSS?

Tags: css, grid

I am trying to create a background for my project. When I use the below css

```
.srd-demo-canvas {
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1px, transparent 2px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 1px, transparent 2px);
}
```

I obtain the following view:

[image]

However, I want a background which has some big squares and has some small squares in them which is something like following:
[image]

What should I add or remove to my CSS code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify it like this using 4 linear-gradients:

```css
body {
  background-size: 72px 72px, 72px 72px, 24px 24px, 24px 24px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5) 2px, transparent 2px), linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) 1px, transparent 1px);
  background-position: -2px -2px, -2px -2px, -1px -1px, -1px -1px;
}
```

Comment: this is absolutely what i want. Thank you so much.